# Bumblebee does not work witn nvidia-355-vulkan beta driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am trying Nvidia vulkan beta driver called "nvidia-355.00.26" on my optimus laptop (intel + nvidia)

You can gen nvidia vulkan beta driver in this PPA:
The driver does not create "common" modules like nvidia-current nvidia-shi etc..., but nvidia_355 nvidia_355_uvm nvidiafb

When I set /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
KernelDriver=nvidia_355

I get

```
Feb 18 14:41:07 usb-tmp bumblebeed[11115]: [13580.233034] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 11130 does not belong to any known session
Feb 18 14:41:07 usb-tmp bumblebeed[11115]: [13580.233050] [WARN][XORG] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
Feb 18 14:41:07 usb-tmp bumblebeed[11115]: [13580.233057] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia355
Feb 18 14:41:07 usb-tmp bumblebeed[11115]: [13580.233061] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia355" (module does not exist, 0)
Feb 18 14:41:07 usb-tmp bumblebeed[11115]: [13580.233068] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
Feb 18 14:41:07 usb-tmp bumblebeed[11115]: [13580.233072] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

I did change /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia_355"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
```

It looks like a bug?

Comment: Who told you that this beta driver is/shoild/will-be/is-supposed-to-be supported by bumblebee?

Comment: I didn't know that there needs to be special nvidia proprietary driver for bumblebee

Comment: A special driver is not needed. But a supported one IS needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the userspace driver was broken, the nvidia_drm.so, some mess with alternatives. I did the purge and install

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-355*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
#reboot
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
#reboot
```

Evrything (opengl and vulkan) works!
(except glmark2 segfaults, maybe other issue?)

Comment: how does vulkan work? Do you need to optirun/primusrun it? Can you install the intel one together with the nvidia one?

Answer (score -1):

You could try this edit:

```
kernel_driver=nvidia_i355
```

and then run a boot-repair, and type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu
```

and then this

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and choose common repair, and it might work.

Comment: thanks. I did not have problems with booting, since intel did work ok. nvidia is just for 3D (no output)